# Concise Explanation of Core.logic

Tags: clojure, scheme, logic-programming, minikanren, clojure-core.logic

I want to use Clojure's Core.logic. However, I want to also understand how it works. Is there a concise explanation of it somewhere? (Like implementing a metacircular evaluator?)

Thanks!

Comment: Why was this closed as OT?  To the OP, have a look at https://github.com/clojure/core.logic/wiki/A-Core.logic-Primer.

Comment: no idea.  have voted to reopen.

Comment: This question is well suited for this tag.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

core.logic is an implementation of miniKanren - originally written and designed in Scheme by Dan Friedman, William  Byrd, Oleg Kiselyov and others. It is an attempt to embed Prolog-style relational programming within Lisp.

If you want to understand how it works you'll need to read the first three chapters of William Byrd's dissertation: https://scholarworks.iu.edu/dspace/bitstream/handle/2022/8777/Byrd_indiana_0093A_10344.pdf?sequence=1

The Reasoned Schemer also covers the unifier in detail. However the much more subtle goal portion of miniKanren isn't given a comprehensive treatment - you'll need to look at Byrd's dissertation for that.

Even then, as with meta-circular interpreters - many insights cannot be gained without trying to implement the system yourself in a variety of programming languages.

Comment: I'd add: https://github.com/clojure/core.logic/wiki/A-Core.logic-Primer as well as the advice to look into programming in Prolog (more examples, similar ideas, though less versatile than miniKanren).

Comment: Your link to Byrd's thesis is broken. :-(

Answer (score 2):

You can also see [David's talk on core.logic](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=A7de6pC-tnU) from the Strange Loop 2012.

And for very light introduction to the topic see also: [sokuza-kanren](https://gist.github.com/3952082)